# Is AUTO-INCREMENT a constraint in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, constraints

I tried searching the same on google but all the answers explain what the Auto-increment keyword is but never really answer the question.

Comment: _"is it a constraint?"_ - as opposed to? (Are you asking if MySQL considers it a _de jure_ `CONSTRAINT` object like `PRIMARY KEY`, `FOREIGN KEY`, `CHECK`, `DEFAULT`, and `UNIQUE` constraints? or if it's "just" a column-modifier? - or are you asking if it's supported at all by MySQL? (in which case yes, it is)

Comment: No. `AUTO_INCREMENT` is just a mechanism to generate values at the database level. In the SQL Standard this is known as `IDENTITY GENERATED BY DEFAULT`.

Comment: @TheImpaler Can you use `UPDATE` to replace/overwrite values in an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column? (in SQL Server, you cannot insert or edit `IDENTITY` columns without using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName ON|OFF` first, I'm curious how MySQL compares...)

Comment: The standard does not stipulate limitations to update primary keys. You can do as needed. However, some database engines impose some [rather artificial] restrictions on it. On the flip side, you may be talking about the other option `IDENTITY GENERATED ALWAYS`; this one cannot be updated, since the value from the database takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually used on the pk column, so that it is auto incremented based on the previous max pk when inserting. Assuming your pk is a number

Comment: okay but is it a constraint? The constraints I'm referring to are CHECK, NOT NULL, DEFAULT, PK,FK.